# Can't convert string to lower case in Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

I have a functioning RUTA script.  All I want to do is convert a string variable to lowercase doing this `ASSIGN(s1, toLowerCase(s2))` where both s1 and s2 are strings.  My script works when I do this `ASSIGN(s1,s2)` but causes an error when I add toLowerCase to my script.  The error I get is not very helpful.

2021-08-28 11:27:39  ERROR AnnotateFileHandler:67 - org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException: Initialization of annotator class "org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine" failed.  (Descriptor: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer posted by Peter.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386131/uima-ruta-script-with-stringfunctions-doesnt-work-when-executing-from-uima-fit/39397196#39397196)

I had to change the way I was configuring my Ruta engine to import the string functions, like this:

```
 createEngineDescription(RutaEngine.class,
            RutaEngine.PARAM_MAIN_SCRIPT, "system8.annotator.system8",
            RutaEngine.PARAM_ADDITIONAL_EXTENSIONS,
            new String[]{
                BooleanOperationsExtension.class.getName(),
                StringOperationsExtension.class.getName()})
```

Thank goodness for Peter Kluegl